# SecPadding is deprecated, what is the equivalent of .PKCS1?

Tags: ios, deprecated, commoncrypto

`SecPadding` is deprecated in iOS 15, it is replaced by `SecKeyAlgorithm`. So then I wonder, is `.rsaEncryptionPKCS1` the same as the old `.PKCS1` when using SecPadding?